# How to vertically align a Stencil component with an HTML element using flex?

Tags: javascript, web-component, stenciljs

```
return (
       <a href="javascript:;" class={`dropdown-item ${this.checkboxColor}`}>
          {this.checkable && <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class={`form-check-input`} />}
          <ifx-icon icon={this.icon}></ifx-icon>
          <label htmlFor="checkbox4" class="form-check-label"><slot /></label>
        </a>
    )
```

I want to vertically-align `ifx-icon` with the `<label>` using `flex` and `align-items: center`.
The container `dropdown-item` already has flex applied, but it's not being applied to the `ifx-icon's` element, because as you know, styles are applied to the component wrapper itself, not the element that's inside.

What do you suggest I do in this case?

Comment: could you put your code in the sandbox so we could run it see how is looks like now, also your css file would help

Comment: @sillyknight02 How do I run a stencil component on sandbox?

Comment: You can use https://webcomponents.dev/ but the component package needs to be on NPM or have a public URL (see [the docs](https://webcomponents.dev/docs/imports#import-modules))

Comment: try `vertical-align:middle` css property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated:

> styles are applied to the component wrapper itself, not the element that's inside

which means that you need to make sure the element or elements that are inside the host element are properly laid out and respond to any style applied to the host element that is desired.

Assuming the `render` function you shared is for the `dropdown-item` component, applying style to that component would only affect the `<a>` element, not its contents, as you already know. You need to add style to your `dropdown-item` component so that the `<a>` lays out the icon and label property.

That would probably look something like:

**dropdown-item.scss**

```css
:host {
    a.dropdown-item {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

You might also be able to use CSS parts to apply the style from outside the component:

```
return (
    <a part="container" ...>
        {this.checkable && <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox4" class={`form-check-input`} />}
        <ifx-icon icon={this.icon}></ifx-icon>
        <label htmlFor="checkbox4" class="form-check-label"><slot /></label>
    </a>
)
```

```css
dropdown-item::part(container) {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```